# script-file Not found by linker

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, linker-scripts

when running a makefile, which includes a usage of
a script-file, I receive an error saying the linker doesn't find the script file.
When running the make file the output is as follows:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc        -g -Wall -Werror                               -c -o main.o main.c
arm-none-eabi-gcc        -g -Wall -Werror                               -c -o misc.o misc.c
arm-none-eabi-gcc        main.o misc.o misc.h                         -g -Wall -Werror                                -Wl,-Map=HOST.map -T=msp432p401r.lds        -o HOST
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot open linker script file =msp432p401r.lds: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:11: HOST] Error 1
```

The makefile content is:

```
#----   Variables (machine depending)   --------
TARGET = HOST
CC     = arm-none-eabi-gcc              #gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Werror                                        # compiler flags
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Map=$(TARGET).map -T=msp432p401r.lds              # linker flag
SOURCE = main.c misc.c misc.h
OBJS   = $(SOURCE:.c=.o)                                         # replace all c with o

#----   Targets          ----------- 
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

I have searched a lot for a solution for this issue, and tried various fixes, with no success.
The script file is located at the same location as the source files.
What can be the reason for not finding the file?
Thanks

Comment: The error message says that file `=msp432p401r.lds` was not found. Did you try `-T msp432p401r.lds` instead of `-T=msp432p401r.lds`?

Comment: Thanks! that indeed solved the issue.
it didn't occur to me that this might be the issue, why is there a syntax different between the map file and the script file?

Comment: I think single letter options (`T`) follow a kind of _short options_ style (argument separated by zero or more spaces) while multiple letters options (`Map`) follow a kind of _long options_ style (argument separated by `=` or spaces). Moreover, multiple letters options can be preceded by two dashes. If you find it easier to remember, or more logical, you can thus use `--Map=$(TARGET).map -T msp432p401r.lds` or `-Map $(TARGET).map -T msp432p401r.lds`.